# I installed a TFS 2010 server, how do I log in + add more users?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I installed a Windows TFS server, 2010, to Windows 7 Ultimate, to my local machine.  I port forwarded and everything.

The question now is: How do I log in, and how do I add more users?

I saw a question similar to this, but it didn't include the log in part :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it the easiest with the [TFS Admin Tools](https://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/). But you can also do it from the commandline (tfssecurity.exe) and directly from within [Visual Studio](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/srlteam/archive/tags/TFS+Permissions/default.aspx).

Comment: How would you log in? I put in my IP, ports, and then it tells me to log in.  I put in my user name and password.  It doesn't work.  It says I either entered the wrong credentials or I do not have permissions.  It does work if I have the ip as localhost though.

Comment: Make sure that in the IIS settings the site is properly configured to be bound to all your IP addresses. If you're using a domain make sure you enter DOMAIN\user as the username, if you're using local accounts make sure you enter YOUR-PC-NAME\user.

Answer (score 0):

First the account that you used to install TFS will be the Admin of the TFS, so you just open the Visual studio and from team menu, click on connect to Team Foundation Server

[image]

[image]